# How to auto-import Rust submodules

Tags: rust, module, include

Is there a way for me to get around having to explicitly `use` every module I declare (without fully qualifying them either)?

I'm following a Rust tutorial that has me splitting up a module to separate some code, and then I'm using all of the submodules in some code in the parent module. So the module folder looks something like this (The tutorial is for using an ECS)

- systems/

  - mod.rs
  - player_input.rs
  - hud.rs
  - movement.rs

and in `mod.rs` I've got the following code:

```rust
    mod player_input;
    mod hud;
    mod movement;
    
    use self::{player_input::*, hud::*, movement::*}
```

if I try to shorten the use statement to `use self::*;` I get this error:

```
... unresolved import `self::*`
| use self::*;
|     ^^^^^^^ cannot glob-import a module into itself
```

I realize after reading this a little further that I'd have to recursively import the submodules, so that makes sense, but is there a way for me to avoid having to explicitly use all my sub-modules (or fully qualifying them).

I know I can just let my editor automatically use things as I type, but that still leaves a mess at the top of my code file and I don't like to "Just let the IDE handle it" if I can avoid it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working off of [drewtato's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77796520/162212) I was able to poke around crates.io and find a crate that provides a similar but slightly more flexible macro: https://crates.io/crates/dry-mods. If you want to avoid an extra third party dependency then his macro works perfectly.

Using the dry-mods crate looks like this:

```rust
dry_mods::mods! {
    mod use player_input;
    mod use hud;
    mod use movement;
}
```

which expands to the following:

```rust
mod player_input;
use player_input::*;
mod hud;
use hud::*;
mod movement;
use movement::*;
```

**Note**: There are a couple tradeoffs to using a macro for this kind of thing: the dry-mods crate still ends up suppressing unused import messages as that check doesn't appear to work on `use` statements generated in a macro (or at least I'm assuming that's what's happening). And if you're relying on something like VSCode's code actions to generate new modules from a mod statement that won't work inside this macro either.

Answer (score 2):

A simple macro can do this.

```rust
macro_rules! modules {
    ($(mod $name:ident;)*) => {
        $(
            mod $name;
            #[allow(unused_imports)]
            use $name::*;
        )*
    };
}

modules! {
    mod a;
    mod b;
    mod c;
}
```

This expands to:

```rust
mod a;
#[allow(unused_imports)]
use a::*;
mod b;
#[allow(unused_imports)]
use b::*;
mod c;
#[allow(unused_imports)]
use c::*;
```

Comment: Oh interesting, yeah that works pretty well. I feel like I saw something similar somewhere, is something like this available in a crate?

Comment: I also just noticed an unfortunate side-effect: This breaks VSCode/rust-analyzer's ability to create missing modules. Pretty minor thing to work around though by just creating the module first ‍♂️.

Comment: The unused imports thing is odd, I actually like having that on the imported modules but Rust is catching that within the macro itself before it's executed so I get warnings if I remove it.

Answer (score 1):

You could [`include!`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.include.html) those files instead of making them submodules:

```rust
include!("player_input.rs");
include!("hud.rs");
include!("movement.rs");
```

But I really wouldn't, the macro documentation itself recommends against using it this way.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know about `include!` though yeah I get why that's not the best.